# how to refer only to the input field in the form I submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have number of forms in my page (lets says 2). i want to submit them with ajax.

how do I "tell" my script to refer only to the input field in the form I submitted (and not to the other one)?

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" id="addCommentForm4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[pageName]' value='<?PHP echo $_GET['page'] ?>' id="pageName" />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[refID]' value='4' id="refID" />

    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment[text]" id="textArea"></textarea>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class='multi form-control' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="files"/>
    <a class="btn btn-primary submit" id="submit" refID='4'>Send</a>

</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" id="addCommentForm5" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[pageName]' value='<?PHP echo $_GET['page'] ?>' id="pageName" />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[refID]' value='5' id="refID" />

    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment[text]" id="textArea"></textarea>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class='multi form-control' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="files"/>
    <a class="btn btn-primary submit" id="submit" refID='5'>Send</a>

</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {

        var element = $(this);
        var refID = element.attr("refID");
        alert(refID);

        var file_data = $('#addCommentForm'+refID+' #files').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file[]', file_data);
        var files_data =  form_data;

        var act = 'add';
        form_data.append('act', act);
        form_data.append('comment[text]',  $("#textArea").val());   
        form_data.append('comment[pageName]',  $("#pageName").val());   
        form_data.append('comment[refID]',  $("#refID").val()); 


        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "ajax/addComment.php",

               dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
               cache: false,
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,  

               data: form_data,
               success: function(data)
               {
                    $('#commentsBox').html(data);
               }

             });

        return false; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `id`'s are not unique. `$("#textArea").val()` won't know which value to take! You can use `$(this).parents('form').serialize()` to get the form data from the submit button.

Comment: can i do this: form_data.$(this).parents('form').$("#textArea").val(); ?

Comment: No, that's not valid jQuery. You probably want something like `$(this).parents('form').find('textarea')`. This finds the textarea by looking for the tag name instead of the id. The duplicate ids need to go, otherwise `$("#textArea")` will never return something useful